# Comma Placement: "From x to y and z"

Tags: punctuation, commas, comparisons

While writing an essay the other day, I was curious about how to correctly phrase a sentence such as the one below:
"From dogs, to cats and fish, owning a pet can allow for a multitude of mental, physical, and emotional benefits."

Is the grammar in this sentence correct? I am most interested in finding the correct comma placement in a phrase such as "from x to y and z," in which x, y, and z are not necessarily nouns. I recognize that I could change the phrase to "from x to y to z."

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would tend to say "From dogs to cats to fish, ..."

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/299547

Answer (score 1):

This "from to" formulation is wrong, because the from-to construction indicates 2 extremes and can’t really be used to denote a list in this fashion. "**From dogs and cats to fish**" is more acceptable.

Comment: I think she could say "from dogs to cats to fish."  Nothing wrong with that.  But if she wants to use commas, I'd add the extra comma:  "from dogs, to cats, to fish."

Comment: "From x to y to z" is correct for the route joining x to z, where y is a waypoint. In the animals case, there is no obvious order in the list. However, If you another noun to the list, it gives "from dogs to cats to snakes to fish" that one may use if the objective is to emphasize the variation.

Comment: Graffito, do you have a reference for your idea that "the from-to constructions indicates 2 extremes"?

Comment: @Graffito - *from A to Z* is a classic example of this use, *from the beginning to the end*. It can be used as a waypoint, but that does not make sense in the list of animals.

Comment: I understand that "from A to Z" is correct, but "from A to B to C" is also correct.

Comment: @ewormuth - Basically, dictionaries define "from" as a preposition indicating an original location, situation or a period of time
and "to" as a destination or a point of limit in time, what confirms the notion of 2 extremes. At my knowledge, they don't define these words as introducing or ending an enumeration.

Comment: I agree with Graffito. From ... to denotes the start and end of an ordered series. Thus, from dogs to cats is almost meaningless, as there is no such series of animals. From A to Z is sensible, as is from 1 to 9. However, the start and end of the ordered series need not coincide with the start and end of some conventionally recognised series such as A..Z or 1 to 9. That is to say that from...to does not identify extremes; we may also refer correctly to sub-series such as from G to M or from 3 to 8.

Comment: I still can't find a reference that says the "from-to" construction is only appropriate with two extremes.  I did, however, find a sentence in a New York Times article that supports my point that "from A to B to C" is an appropriate construction:  "Their apparent retreat threatens to bear heavily on everything from the region’s drinking water supply to agricultural production to disease and floods." NYT, 7/17/07

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this comma conundrum you might want to rewrite the sentence: "Whether you own a dog, cat, or fish, owning a pet provides many mental, physical and emotional benefits."

I've removed "can allow" because it's not good English.  Multitude is unnecessarily wordy, and mental emotional doesn't make sense.

In the future, if you face these kinds of things, consider rewriting the sentence...that usually solves the problems.  Bad writing always needs justification; good writing speaks for itself.