# How to punctuate " from to to to"

Tags: grammar, punctuation

“This passage moves from confession and petition, to affirmation, to questioning, to affirmation, and ends in petition."

Comment: "Tinker to Evers to Chance" has no punctuation.

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/299547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think without commas is correct, but it doesn’t seem right here. If there were just two stages, it wouldn’t be too bad, but five! I’d reword the sentence to read something like this:
This passage goes through a series of modes: confession and petition, affirmation, questioning, affirmation again, and ends in petition.