# Listing multiple nouns with "to" in between?

Tags: grammaticality

Would it be grammatically correct to list multiple nouns with "to" in between?

For example, "I've never seen so many desserts (from cakes to ice cream to cupcakes to cookies)."

I've tried to do some research to see if this sentence format has been used before, but all I could find was:

> Cognitive linguists such as Mark Turner and Gilles Fauconnier, building off of the work of George Lakoff (Metaphors We Live By), have emphasized the analogical process of conceptual “blending” as being core to every level of human cognition, from discerning images to creative writing to applying mathematical concepts to the world.

**Source:** "Why the Chess Computer Deep Blue Played Like a Human", David Auerbach (https://nautil.us/issue/18/genius/why-the-chess-computer-deep-blue-played-like-a-human?curator=MediaREDEF)

My apologies if this is an inappropriate question. I'm not a great writer (although I'm trying to improve) and my goal is to try and illustrate expansiveness through the listing of various examples (for example, my dessert example). However, I'm unsure if this would be grammatically correct.

Comment: The usual sense of 'from... to' is to indicate both ends of a range, as in _I love desserts, from a simple vanilla ice cream to an elaborate gateau_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there two "to"s in "from ... to ... to ..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299547/why-are-there-two-tos-in-from-to-to)